# SDL_mixer 2 compilation broken in windows using visual studio express with SDL2

Tags: c++, windows-xp, compiler-errors, sdl, sdl-mixer

Im trying to compile SDL_mixer 2 with SDL2 checked out the latest code from :
http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_mixer
also compiled with no problem SDL2 and SDL_image.

when compiling SDL_mixer im getting the compilation errors :

```
1>Compiling...
1>dynamic_mp3.c
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2371: 'SDL_Rect' : redefinition; different basic types
1>        d:\cpp\2d\love\lov8\lib\sdl\include\sdl_rect.h(69) : see declaration of 'SDL_Rect'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2371: 'SMPEG_FilterInfo' : redefinition; different basic types
1>        d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(33) : see declaration of 'SMPEG_FilterInfo'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(46) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SMPEG_FilterCallback'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(48) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(56) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(59) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2081: 'SMPEG_Filter' : name in formal parameter list illegal
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>mixer.c
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2371: 'SDL_Rect' : redefinition; different basic types
1>        d:\cpp\2d\love\lov8\lib\sdl\include\sdl_rect.h(69) : see declaration of 'SDL_Rect'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2371: 'SMPEG_FilterInfo' : redefinition; different basic types
1>        d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(33) : see declaration of 'SMPEG_FilterInfo'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(46) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SMPEG_FilterCallback'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(48) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(56) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(59) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2081: 'SMPEG_Filter' : name in formal parameter list illegal
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\mixer.c(129) : warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\mixer.c(1145) : warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
1>music.c
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2371: 'SDL_Rect' : redefinition; different basic types
1>        d:\cpp\2d\love\lov8\lib\sdl\include\sdl_rect.h(69) : see declaration of 'SDL_Rect'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2371: 'SMPEG_FilterInfo' : redefinition; different basic types
1>        d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(33) : see declaration of 'SMPEG_FilterInfo'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(39) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(46) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SMPEG_FilterCallback'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(48) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(56) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(59) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\mpegfilter.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2081: 'SMPEG_Filter' : name in formal parameter list illegal
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\visualc\external\include\smpeg.h(180) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\music.c(166) : warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\music.c(625) : warning C4047: 'return' : 'Mix_Music *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
1>d:\cpp\2d\sdl2.0\sdl-2.0\sdl_mixer\music.c(1529) : warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
```

any one has any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the MP3_MUSIC preprocessor macro or include smpeg in you search path.

Comment: i do want to be able to play mp3

Comment: Do you turned SDL_NO_COMPAT on? If you do so, you will lost the definition of SDL_Overlay.

Comment: in SDL2 there is no indication about SDL_NO_COMPAT in sources only in 
test\test-automation\src\runner\Makefile.am
and in test\automated\Makefile , also in SDL_mixer no SDL_NO_COMPAT in source

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PreProcessor Definitions.

Remove these

```
MOD_MUSIC
MOD_DYNAMIC=\"libmikmod-2.dll\"
OGG_MUSIC
OGG_DYNAMIC=\"libvorbisfile-3.dll\"
FLAC_MUSIC
FLAC_DYNAMIC=\"libFLAC-8.dll\"
MP3_MUSIC
MP3_DYNAMIC=\"smpeg.dll\"
```

If you want to use any of those file types in your audio, you need to get those .dll files as well. I would recommend compiling those libraries statically instead of dynamically to make thing more cross-platform compatible.